# Is cross dressing immoral or forbidden by the bible

Tags: catholicism, sin

I am a catholic young man. I’m straight but I recently started and am enjoying cross dressing.I have been enjoying the look of female fashion quite a bit more then male fashion for about 7 years now.

I’m kind of a bible/theology noob so I am wondering if enjoying certain things, like paintings my nails or wearing leggings is immoral. I can’t see anything wrong with it, but I don’t actually know enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The only Bible passage that comes to mind is this quote from Deuteronomy:

> A woman must not wear men’s clothing, nor a man wear women’s clothing,
>   for the LORD your God detests anyone who does this. (Deuteronomy 22:5,
>   NIV)

Feel free to ask God if He has changed his mind on this issue.